# How to test for a stamped WinCe6 NK.BIN image!

Tags: image, windows-ce, platform-builder

I have created an image, using Platform Builder, for Windows CE6.

As per the legal agreement, I then 'licensed' the NK.BIN image file, again using Platform Builder, using a purchased run-time key that came with 100 licenses.

How can I test that this process has worked?

What is 'different' in the image? Is there a command/action that can be performed to identify a legally stamped CE6 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to determine if the NK.bin has been built with the correct PID then Stampbin should do the trick:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504718.aspx

Otherwise a search on Viewbin seems to be positive as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms938075.aspx:

You can use Viewbin.exe tool like "viewbin -t nk.bin" which will give an output comprised of PID[0] - PID[9]. If all these values are 0x00000000 then it means your runtime image is not stamped, otherwise it is stamped.